# How to get variable by select in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want get variable with sql query:

```
Dt = spark.sql("""select max(dt) from table""")

Script = """select * from table where dt > """ + dt

Spark.sql(script)
```

but when I try to substitute a variable in the request I get error:
"Can only concatenate str (not dataframe) to str"

How do I get the variable  as a string and not a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

To get the result in a variable, you can use `collect()` and extract the value. Here's an example that pulls the max date-month (YYYYMM) from a table and stores it in a variable.

```
max_mth = spark.sql('select max(mth) from table').collect()[0][0]

print(max_mth)
# 202202
```

You can either cast the value to string in the sql statement, or use `str()` on the variable while using to convert the integer value to string.

*P.S. - the `[0][0]` is to select the first row-column*