# How do i save a single value output of a Spark.SQL output as a variable to use further in code

Tags: python, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried using the below option, but it is saving the value as a data frame, but I only need the value as a variable for processing

```py
value = spark.read.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("query", SQL).load()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72782975/8279585 -- this might help

Answer (score 1):

To store the value to a variable, you need an actual `action`. The `.load` you have in there is just a pointer to the underlying data. It doesn't materialize your query.

One way is to create a temp view and perform a `first` or `collect` action after `spark.sql()` call.

```
spark.read \
     .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake") \
     .options(**sfOptions) \ 
     .option("query", SQL) \ --feel free to remove this 
     .load() \
     .createOrReplaceTempView("my_data")

my_var = spark.sql("select that single value from my_data").first()[0]
```