# How to convert pyspark df to python string?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I just want to show you the way "How to convert pyspark df to python string?".
Task: get a python string from a pyspark dataframe.

If you know how to make this easier, let me know!)

1. I got df from spark.sql()

```
sql = f"""
SELECT max(calculation_dt) max_calc FROM default.table
"""

max_calc_dt = spark.sql(sql)
```

It returned only one row:
+----------+
|  max_calc|
+----------+
|2023-07-31|
+----------+

2. Change type of col max_calc from date to str:

```
a = max_calc_dt.select(col('max_calc').cast('string')) #change type of col max_calc from date to str
```

3. Convert df to rdd:

```
a_rdd = a.rdd.collect()
```

4. Get python str:
   There are two ways: use cycle "for" or get values using index.
   I'll show you the second option:

```
res = a_rdd[0]['max_calc'].strip()
print(res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get variable by select in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782975/how-to-get-variable-by-select-in-spark)

Comment: @samkart , thanks, it works correctly!